# Using CASE to align values with user IDs

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which is a custom data table where name value pairs exist. Here's an example of some custom data in this table for an individual:

```
table custom_data
    user_id | custom_data_name | custom_data_value
    123 | initial contact date | 2014-01-01
    123 | subscription start date | 2014-02-02
    123 | favorite fruit | pears
```

I would like to create a query that parses this out at the individual level so I can see the data side by side like this:

```
user_id | initial_contact_date | subscription_start_date
123 | 2014-01-01 | 2014-02-02
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT 
        user_id,
        CASE WHEN base1.custom_data_name = 'initial contact date' THEN custom_data.data END AS initial_contact_date,
        CASE WHEN base1.custom_data_name = 'subscription start date' THEN custom_data.data END AS subscription_start_date
    FROM
        (
        SELECT * FROM custom_data
        WHERE custom_data_name = 'initial contact date' OR custom_data_name = 'subscription start date') base1
    GROUP BY user_id
```

But I'm having a hard time interpreting the results. The results show, for each user, a value for EITHER initial_contact_date or subscription_start_date but not both together in one record.

How would I do that?

Comment: The EAV anti pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  user_id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN custom_data_name = 'initial contact date' THEN custom_data_value END) AS initial_contact_date,
  MAX(CASE WHEN custom_data_name = 'subscription start date' THEN custom_data_value END) AS subscription_start_date
  --MAX(CASE WHEN custom_data_name = 'favorite fruit' THEN custom_data_value END) AS favorite_fruit 
FROM custom_data
GROUP BY user_id
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1fd8c/6)

Answer (score 2):

You need to aggregate the data

```
select user_id
     , min(case 
             when custom_data_name = 'initial contact date' then custom_data_value
           end) initialContactDate
     , min(case 
             when custom_data_name = 'subscription start date' then custom_data_value
           end) subscriptionStartDate

  from (
    select '123' user_id, 'initial contact date' custom_data_name, '2014-01-01' custom_data_value union all
    select '123' user_id, 'subscription start date' custom_data_name, '2014-01-02' custom_data_value union all
    select '123' user_id, 'favorite fruit' custom_data_name, 'pears' custom_data_value
  ) tt
 group by user_id

USER_ID     INITIALCONTACTDATE  SUBSCRIPTIONSTARTDATE
-----------------------------------------------------
    123             2014-01-01             2014-01-02
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/45459)

Comment: Thanks for the answer I appreciate that. Accepted @jpw's answer only because his came up sooner.